# S3 vs Redis instance for frequent low-latency reads from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, redis

I have a JSON file that gets updated manually, let’s say, once a week.

I have an AWS Lambda that gets invoked, up to, once every 10 seconds which needs to read this JSON file

I could store this JSON file in S3 and call GetObject on every Lamdba invocation, or I could stuff the JSON blob into a Redis (hosted in same region as Lambda) key and also fetch it every invocation

Architecturally - what is the optimal way to read infrequently-changing data (but that is 0.5mb in size) from a Lambda that’s fairly frequently invoked?

Comment: Does the json file change constantly?

Comment: @Marcin very infrequently, “ once a week.”

Comment: How critical is it that the lambda has the currently up-to-date file available? You could just load the file during the lambda invocation and then cache it in the lambda itself. Invocations that hit the same execution environment can use the cached s3 object directly, new execution environments always get the file once and then cache it again.

Comment: @luk2302 roughly how long do those execution environments last? How does one cache in a Lambda?

Comment: 1-2 hours max. You cache by keeping something in global state, how that looks in practice depends on the language, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61720907/2442804 for python, https://rewind.com/blog/simple-caching-in-aws-lambda-functions/ in node.

Comment: Alternatively, you can download and save the file in the /tmp folder, but the lifetime of the /tmp file storage depends on the lambda instance lifetime. IMO, it would be better to save the config file in EFS, and it will let you share the same file with other lambda instances, moreover, it will give better performance.